# Azure Front Door rule set to URL rewrite with and without trailing slash

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I currently have a rule applied to an origin group that half works but I would like to get it working for the both scenarios below

The route is setup in Azure Front Door with both `/test1/*` and `/test1`

These example URIs would route to the same origin group (a web app) which should ultimately be at `example.com/test1/test2/`

1. `example.com/test1/a` -> `example.com/test1/test2/a`
2. `example.com/test1/b` -> `example.com/test1/test2/b`
3. `example.com/test1/` -> `example.com/test1/test2/`
4. `example.com/test1` -> `example.com/test1/test2`

I can get the first 3 to work with the below rule but I cannot get #4 to work.

[image]

What should the rule, or additional rule, be to capture the fourth case?